# Error with map markers not showing up with correct style

Tags: google-fusion-tables

When I use the Fusion API to remove all rows from a table and then add new rows to it, the map markers show up as the default markers, not the ones I have defined.
For example, I have the map below:
https://www.google.com/fusiontables/embedviz?q=select+col2+from+1YPVj8gN3lBEDE9NHBSIXHqOyb9h8kqPviqG42Yo&viz=MAP&h=false&lat=48.04804748460389&lng=-97.86780852499999&t=1&z=4&l=col2&y=7&tmplt=6
It is set to use the Icon column in the fusion table for the map markers.
When I remove all the rows and add them back in through the API, all the markers show up as the default red dots.
If I go to Tools->Change Map Styles and set it to Fixed->red dot and save, the map updates and shows the red dots.
If I then repeat that and set it back to using the Icon column, then the map refreshes and the style is applied correctly.
If I do not do this, then no matter what happens or how long I wait or if I clear my cache, the markers use the incorrect style.

Has anyone run into this? Any google people reading this have some insight?

Answer (score 1):

There is a two minute cache applied to embedded map tiles, so you could just be seeing that delay. If you give it some time and you still see the problem, then something else is going on. The HTTP request and response headers from one of the faulty tiles would be helpful in diagnosing the issue.